# Twilio returns a 401 unauthorized when using the Python SDK on Heroku

Tags: python, rest, heroku, flask, twilio

If I run my message forwarding server locally with `ngrok` it works, but if I deploy it Heroku however, I get a `401 unauthorized` error.

My server works as follows:

1. First, from my phone, messages go to Twilio.
2. Twilio sends my app a request at `/`.
3. The app forwards the SMS body to another number, using the [python
   SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install) to create and send a message to that number.

Twilio does expect to forward numbers to my Heroku app, I've listed the callback urls on the number.
I've also checked all my environment variables in Heroku, they are correct and contain the right keys and such, and are named properly.

My app:

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
import twilio.twiml
import os

# log to stderr
import logging
from logging import StreamHandler


app = Flask(__name__)
file_handler = StreamHandler()
app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  # set the desired logging level here
app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)

# if getting variables from config py file use:
# app.config.from_pyfile('path/to/config/config.py')

# if using variables from environment variables
print os.environ.keys()
client = TwilioRestClient(os.environ['ACCOUNT_SID'], os.environ['AUTH_TOKEN'])

shannon = os.environ['SHANNON']
nic = os.environ['NIC']
twilio_number_uk = os.environ['TWILIO_NUMBER_UK']
twilio_number_us = os.environ['TWILIO_NUMBER_US']

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def forwardMessages():
    """Forwards texts from Shannon (US) to Nic (UK) through Twilio API.
    Useful for those without international texting"""
    app.logger.debug("We're in the home request")
    sender = request.values.get("From")
    sms_body = request.values.get("Body")

    if sender and sms_body:


      if sender == shannon:
      # if it's from Shannon
        forward_number = nic
        from_number = twilio_number_uk
        #forward to NIC
      else:
        # if it's from not SHANNON
        forward_number = shannon
        from_number = twilio_number_us
        # forward to Shannon
      forward_message = client.sms.messages.create(to=forward_number, from_=from_number, body=sms_body)

      resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
      app.logger.debug("Response from Twilio: " + str(resp))
      return str(resp)

    else:
      return "Got your request"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    print "Magic happenin' on port %d" % port
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I've had lots of people look at this and no one can figure it out!
Please help!

Comment: You checked env. variables on remote machine from OS admin panel (or similar) or during your run-time ? I see you have debug-printed keys but no values. Try with hard-coded credentials to limit the problem.

Comment: tried adding debugging statements to print the values, which are correct and still returning a 401 authentication error. Perhaps I *might* have run into a bug in Twilio's python client? I'll send their support team a ticket and see. Not sure why it's not authenticating with proper credentials.

Thank you so much for trying to help.